# Three random variables independence

Tags: probability, independence

Is it possible to have such random variables $X, Y, Z$ (for simplicity let them be discrete) that:
$$P(X \cap Y) = P(X)P(Y)$$
$$P(X \cap Z) = P(X)P(Z)$$
$$P(Y \cap Z) = P(Y)P(Z)$$

but

$$P(X \cap Y \cap Z) \neq P(X)P(Y)P(Z)$$

in other words $(X, Y)$, $(X, Z)$ and $(Y,Z)$ are independent, but
$(X,Y,Z)$ as a group of three random variables is not ?

Comment: The usual example is to flip a fair penny and a fair dime, let $X$ be the indicator variable for the penny coming up $H$, $Y$ the variable for the dime coming up $H$, and $Z$ the variable for the two coins matching.

Comment: Thanks, lulu! Pretty simple and clear example!

Comment: You use the word "variables" but your probabilities are written as if $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are _events._

Comment: See also [Example of Pairwise Independent but not Jointly Independent Random Variables?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1783225/example-of-pairwise-independent-but-not-jointly-independent-random-variables)