# If $A\bot C$ and $B\bot C$ is $AB\bot C$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

Given three discrete random variables $A, B, C$, for which $A \bot C$ and $B \bot C$, is $(A,B) \bot C$? If so, where can I find a reference on this subject? Someone told me it was true and to search for it in Casella and Berger's book on Statistical Inference, but I could not find it.

Comment: Please specify the meaning of "joint probability $AB\perp C$".  Does $\perp$ mean independent?  Does it make sense to say distributions are independent (and not events are inependent or random variables are independent)?

Comment: @GEdgar Out of curiosity, is there a natural Hilbert space that has probability distributions as vectors?

Comment: @GEdgar Good question! I believe you are right, but what happens with AB? Is it also a (joint) random variable? Yes, $\bot$ means independence.

Comment: The statement is false, I'm sure this question must be a duplicate since I've seen someone post the counterexample quite recently.

Comment: @SuzuHirose It is not a duplicate, at least not an intentional one. Can you point me to this counterexample, please?

Comment: When I say it is a duplicate I am not discussing your intention, I am discussing whether the question has been asked before. This question is certainly a duplicate. Here is one example of a question dealing with this from six years ago. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1783225/example-of-pairwise-independent-but-not-jointly-independent-random-variables

Comment: @GEdgar I have corrected the question. Thx.

Comment: @SuzuHirose I am unsure if the question I am asking is exactly answered in the one you suggested me. Please see that I am not asking for pairwise independence.

Comment: It’s still not clear to me what you mean by $AB\perp C$. As the question is written now I assume you mean the product of $A$ and $B$. But before you said “joint” which I would assume means to ask if $(A,B)$ is independent of $C$. (The answer is no in either case.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen indeed, it is not the product but (A,B).

Comment: Pairwise independence means that $A$ and $B$ are independent and $B$ and $C$ are independent, so in fact you are asking about pairwise independence.

Comment: Then is the same: let $A=XY$, $B=YZ$ and $C=XZ$, where X,Y,Z are independent Rademacher (though this serves equally well as a counterexample to the alternative interpretation). For a maybe slightly easier example, let $A$ come from any symmetric distribution, $C$ be a Rademacher independent of $A$ and $B=AC$.

Comment: Define better what is AB. Are you talking about events or random variables. AB can also mean $A\cap B$ if $A$ and $B$ are events. Or AB is the product of 2 r.vs. Or you want to check whether the joint distribution for A, B and C is the product of the marginal distributions for A, B and C.

Comment: @SuzuHirose yes, but what I mean is that (using your comment's notation), $A$ is not necessarily independent of $C$. So no pairwise independence. In pairwise independence $A \bot B$, $A \bot C$, and $B \bot C$. In that case, it is known that they are not mutually independent. What I am asking seems like a different question.

Comment: Yes but the thing is that if there are counterexamples when all three of them are pairwise independent, then there must be counterexamples when only two of them are pairwise independent, since that is a weaker condition.

Comment: @suzuhirose thx for your time.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen thanks, you have been very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted, this has surely been asked here already.

Example.  Toss a fair coin twice in succession.
Let $A$ be the result of the first toss, $A=0$ for heads and $A=1$ for tails, each with probability $1/2$.
Similarly, let $B$ be the result of the second toss, $B=0$ for heads and $B=1$ for tails, each with probability $1/2$.
Finally, let $C$ be agreement of the tosses: that is $C=0$ if $A=B$ and $C=1$ if $A \ne B$.
Then: $(A,B)$ has four possible outcomes: $(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)$, each with probability $1/4$.

Compute:
$A$ is independent of $C$;
$B$ is independent of $C$;
[not asked] $A$ is independent of $B$;
but $(A,B)$ is not independent of $C$.